# input date - preselect year without setting value?

Tags: html, forms, datepicker

`<input type="date" name="birthday" id="birthdate" required="">`

I'd like to preselect the year of the datepicker (lets say 16 years back), so users may not need to start with todays date, clicking back to their birthyear.

If I use `value="2005-01-01"` the date is preselected but also the input has a `:valid` value, so the field won't show with `:invalid` styling (since its a required field, it has different styling with `:invalid` selector, if it is empty or has wrong syntax). So basically it would no longer be a required field, because it has a valid value, and the user won't need to enter or change the date, to send the form.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is use JavaScript to change the year when the input is changed. Like so:

```js
var chosenYear = 2000;
var datepicker = document.getElementById("birthdate");
datepicker.addEventListener("change", ()=>{
  datepicker.value = chosenYear+datepicker.value.substring(4);
})
```

```html
Please choose your birthdate. <b>The year will automatically be set to 2000.</b>
<br/><br/>
<input type="date" name="birthday" id="birthdate" required="">
```

Comment: this would not allow to choose another year then 2000.

Comment: onfocus="(this.value='2005-01-01')" is the best i found so far. But it still doesn't make sure the user enter a birthdate / fill out the field.